# Comparing float variables precisely?

Tags: python, types, numbers

I have a code looking like this:

```
for i in range (1, 256):
    if ((((i-1) * (1 / float(256))) <= proba) and (proba <= (i * (1 / float(256))))):
        problist[i] += 1
```

With `proba` being a float between 0 and 1 (mostly 0.625 or 0.5).
I want to add `proba` which is calculated before to a specific interval. Problem is that python seems to assign one value to more than one interval due to rounding errors.

Is there another way to compare these two float numbers being more precise?

Comment: Show an actual failing example?

Comment: what are you trying to achive? what `proba` is?

Comment: proba is a probability value that I got from another function. I calculate this probability around 16.000 times and each propability should be assigned to one specific interval.

Answer (score 0):

Has nothing to do with rounding errors. There aren't any. But if you have intervals [0.49609375, 0.5] and [0.5, 0.50390625], then 0.5 truly is in both of them. Use half-open intervals instead, i.e., change one of those `<=` to `<`.

Btw, it would be simpler and faster to simply **calculate** the interval number by multiplying with 256.

```
problist[min(int(proba * 256) + 1, 256)] += 1
```

Comment: changing the operators didn't help. The intervalls are pretty unique with 1/256 precision :/
but the calculate option seems to be helpful. Can you explain a bit more what it does and how it works?

Comment: @Kuroskai If fixing the operators didn't help, then you did it wrong. Please show an example where it still goes wrong. And what do you mean with "unique"?